# Sharing partials across multiple Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I have a set of partials (`user/_comment.html.erb`, for example) that I want to share across multiple Rails applications.

What is the best way to do this? I am leaning towards an Engine at the moment, because I would also like to share some models, but can't figure out how to integrate them.

I have tried creating a Rails engine gem with `app/views/users/_comment.html.erb` and adding it to the Gemfile of the main Rails application, but it cannot find the view (`ActionView::MissingTemplate`). Is there an official way to add the engine to the view path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have described should work. If you add a Gem and especially if it's an engine, Rails adds this gem's `app/` directories to the load path(s) and it should, well, work :) Your render call should be something like: `render "users/comment"`. Oh, and after bundling the gem, the app needs to be restarted as well. Can't think of anything else.

Comment: It does, PEBKAC. I had screwed up my inheriting from `Rails::Engine` and my require.

Comment: For future reference, in order to share partials this way the created gem has to be a Rails Engine.